# Why Lord Balarāma is referred as 'Palm-tree bannered'? Is he 'palm-bannered (Tāla-dhvaja)' or 'plough-bannered (Sīrā-dhvaja)'?

Tags: symbolism, balarama

It is well known that the god Viṣṇu (Kṛṣṇa) is known as Garuḍa-dhvaja - i.e. the Garuḍa-bannered deity, and god Śiva as Vṛṣabha-dhvaja - the bull-bannered deity.

In the Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam  Mahā-Purāṇa, we get a reference for Lord Balarāma referred to as 'tāla-dhvaja (तालध्वज)' - i.e. 'Palm-tree bannered'
.

> [ŚB 10.50.21](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/50/21/)
>  सुपर्ण**तालध्वज**चिह्नितौ रथा-
> वलक्षयन्त्यो हरिरामयोर्मृधे ।
>  स्‍त्रिय: पुराट्टालकहर्म्यगोपुरं
> समाश्रिता: सम्मुमुहु: शुचार्दिता: ॥ २१ ॥
>
> > The women stood in the watchtowers, palaces, and high gates of the
> > city. **When they could no longer see Kṛṣṇa’s and Balarāma’s chariots,
> > identified by banners marked with the emblems of Garuḍa and [a palm
> > tree],** they were struck with grief and fainted.

Further,

Now, we get a small explanation for Balarāma's banner, in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa, as to why Balarāma is referred 'Palm-tree bannered', but that explanation again creates more confusion for me at least.

[Chapter 25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370745.html), Section 2: Puruṣottama-kṣetra-māhātmya, Book 2 - Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa

> तलस्थत्वादसौ तालः सदा तेनांकितः प्रभुः । ततः स एव शेषस्य
> बलभद्रावतारिणः ॥ १४ ॥
>  अथवा सीरिणः कार्यं **सीरमेव ध्वजोत्तमम्** । ध्वजः
> सुनिर्मलः कार्यस्तस्मात्**तालध्वजो** मतः ॥ १५ ॥
>
> > 14. & 15. **The Palm-tree is called Tāla because it is stationed in Tala (surface of the earth). The Lord is always marked with it. Hence that
> >     alone should be made the emblem devoid of impurities, of the
> >     incarnation of Śeṣa as Balabhadra. So he is known as [Tāladhvaja
> >     (having palm tree as the emblem)]. Or the plough (sīrā) alone shall be made
> >     the excellent emblem of the Lord [('Sīrā-dhvaja' i.e, 'Plough bannered')] with one in his hand.**

So, now as per the above two Mahā-Purāṇas, Lord Balarāma is a holder of two different banners as follows:

> 1. Tāla-dhvaja - तालध्वज - The 'Palm tree Bannered '
>
> And
>
> 2. Sīrā-dhvaja - सीरध्वज - The 'Plough-Bannered'

Interestingly, Pitāmaḥ Bhiṣma is also said to have a banner of the Palm tree (decked with five stars though)
 viz. Book 6 - Bhiṣma Parva 17.18 (a) in the Mahābhārata

> तालेन महता भीष्मः पञ्चतारेण केतुना  ॥ [१८.अ](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh06_sa.html) ॥
>
> > 18. [(a).](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375166.html) And with his large palmyra-standard decked with five stars, Bhiṣma,...

But, the explanation given in the Skanda Purāṇa for Balarāma's banner, doesn't seem to concur with
Bhiṣma's similar banner.

---

### Questions:

- **1.** Is there any 'specific detailed story' to that effect, that explains why Lord Balarāma is referred to as Tāladhvaja i.e., 'Palm-tree bannered'? Is the banner symbolic of anything esoteric?

  - <sup>*There is a story in [ŚB 10.15](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/15/) involving the pastimes of Balarāma and Kṛṣṇa in the Vṛndāvana. Both the brothers killed the demon Dhenukāsura and his kins, and thus the residents of Vṛndāvana could savor the fruits of the tāla (Palm) trees. Might this be the reason for Balarāma's 'Palm-tree banner'?*</sup>

- **2.** How come, or why does Balarāma have two dedicated banners for him, viz the 'Palm-tree' and the 'Plough'?

- **3.** Which other scriptures refer Balarāma with the above two banner epithets, either individually (like the Bhāgavatam) or collectively - with both (like the Skanda Purāṇa)?

- **4.** Which other divinity or a being, also have two different banners besides Lord Balarāma?

---

Related: [What were the banners of famous warriors from the Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21067/what-were-the-banners-of-famous-warriors-from-the-mahabharata)

Answer (score 1):

Lord Balarama has Plough and Club for his two weapons. His club is called Sunanda. He used it to kill Rukmi,
fight Dvivida Gorilla
and Jarasandha forces.

He used Plough
to grab Balvala demon,
also to lift Hastinapura,
drag River Yamuna.

Since Chakra and Conch makes us remember Vishnu, Plough makes us remember Lord Balarama who supports Earth and all worlds as Sesha from Paatala. So Plough is a symbol for Lord Balarama.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp139.htm

Comment: Hey, hi! You should cite sources! Also, this doesn't answer my question. Sorry.

Comment: @Vivikta Isn't it answering partially?